# Live Server Responds ExtractValue function is not supported by mysql

Tags: mysql, asp.net, xml

I have Just put an xml structure in my procedure as a Input which is working perfect on local host but when i hosted it, it responds that mysql does not support ExtractValue function.

I have send this code to procedure...

```
string OType = "LogIn";
            ProcedureName = "SP_AgentAction";
            XElement xl = new XElement(
                new XElement("UserId", userid),
                new XElement("Pass", Password)
                );
            ds = objDal.ExecuteDataSet(ProcedureName, CommandType.StoredProcedure, new MySqlParameter("@xml", xl.ToString()));
```

And this is the procedure where i received data.

```
begin
declare UserId,Pass,UserStatus varchar(50);
set UserId=ExtractValue(xml,'/root/UserId');
set Pass=ExtractValue(xml,'/root/Pass');
select us_status,us_fname,us_mname,us_lname,us_usercode 
from us_uxusermaster 
where us_userid=UserId and us_password=Pass;
End
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey Guys Thanks for not responding for my Question but I fount the mistake by my self.
The Mysql version was in a older state i just upgraded it and it worked . 
Thanks.